# Как сделать так, чтобы меню отображалось только на конкретных WordPress Post Type

Tags: wordpress, header, menu

Как сделать так, чтобы меню отображалось только на конкретных WordPress Post Type или на конкретных страницых, а на других Post Type или на конкретных страницах вообще отсутствовало?

Comment: Меню в сайдбаре или хедере?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Плагин "[Menu Swapper](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/menu-swapper/)".

1. Настройки \ Menu Swapper. Создать новые области для меню.
2. Внешний вид \ Меню. Создать новые меню.
3. Там же перейти на вкладку "Управление областями". Распределить новые меню по новым областям.
4. В окне редактирования записей и страниц справа появляется блок "Menu Swapper". В нем два поля, с помощью которых задать замену стандартной области на одну из новых.

Comment: @Arthur Удалось ли решить задачу? Какая помощь нужна?

Answer (score 0):

Окей, есть кое-что для вас. Таким кодом я для каждой категории выводил свою форму поиска.

В нужный шаблон или место на сранице вставляем код:

```
/* проверяем, что тип записи = пост */
<?php if (get_post_type( $post_id ) === 'post'): ?>
/* здесь код, который необходимо выполнить */
<?php endif; ?>
```

аналогично можете делать проверки для категорий и любых страниц, используя функции `in_category('номер категории')`, `is_home` и любые другие.
Надеюсь, поможет.